# iPhone enterprise app icon not showing when over the air installation

Tags: ios, iphone

When we distribute the iOS app using enterprise certificate and when we install the app for the first time, the icon is not showing during installation stage, icon shows after installation.

This behaviour is different from when we install the app through app store. When we install through app store, the icon shows with a dark grey mask.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an iOS bug introduced in recent versions of iOS probably `iOS 11.3`.

Manifest file contains required fields, images are in `PNG` format and using `https` protocol.

After testing installation of the app on different devices and different iOS versions ended up with following results:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╗
║ iOS version ║ Device      ║ Icon visible while installing ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ iOS 9.3.1   ║ iPad mini 4 ║ Yes                           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ iOS 10.3.1  ║ iPhone 6    ║ Yes                           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ iOS 11.1.1  ║ iPad Air 2  ║ Yes                           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ iOS 11.2.6  ║ iPhone 6S   ║ Yes                           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ iOS 11.3.1  ║ iPhone X    ║ No                            ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ iOS 11.3.1  ║ iPhone 6S   ║ No                            ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two png icons (sizes: 57x57, 512x512) to the server where your **.ipa** file is and add their url to the **plist** file which is generated when you export ipa for enterprise. The icon you added will display while downloading the app.

So the .plist file will look like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                     <key>kind</key>
                     <string>software-package</string>
                     <key>url</key>
                     <string>https://ipa-file-location</string>
                </dict>

                <!-- ADD THIS: -->
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://.../img57x57.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>full-size-image</string>
                   <key>url</key>
                   <string>https://.../img512x512.png</string>
                </dict>
               <!---------->

            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>...</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>...</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>...</string>
            </dict>
       </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Same here, I tried to change the plist file following again all recommandations and it didn't fix anything, I think Najdan Tomić is right, it must be a bug :)